# Can I apply Mauchly's test of sphericity to this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If we test the effectiveness of psychotherapy in treatment of depression, by measuring the level of depression before and after the treatment, why can't I apply Mauchly's test?
Or can I?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply [Mauchly's sphericity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauchly's_sphericity_test) without any problems given that the coefficients of interest cotain are within subject terms, rather than a mix or between.

Comment: ok, thanks, so, if I can apply it, then which one of these shoud be the correct answer, if Mauchly's test is applicable: In this case, Mauchly's test will depend on: 1) contingency table with 2 levels, 2)  inverse correlation table 3)covariance table 4)variance table  :(